# How can use __attribute__ (section) for each element of an array?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a multidimensional array and I want to define each element of this array in a different section. Something like:

```
int array [2][200];

array[0] __attribute__((section (".section1")));
array[1] __attribute__((section (".section2")));
```

I know this piece of code is not correct because `__atribute__ ((section "section name"))` should be used in the array definition. Do you have any suggestions on how I can do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you can't. Instead, just have two variables with `int *array[2]`.

Comment: It really seems as if these should be individual variables. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The array is a contigous chunk of memory and elements cannot be in different sections.

C standard (6.2.5.20):

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
> objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.

> Do you have any suggestions on how I can do it?

You need to have two separate arrays in different sections and array of two pointers referencing those arrays.